# How to load Spring message.properties in thymeleaf with th:each

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Enum contains 4 values like created, saved, approved, `enter code here`rejected and for these 4 values i have text to display in front view page in message.properties like i1=Created, i2=Saved, i3=Approved, i4=Rejected

My Code is looks like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = {"text/html;charset=UTF-8"})
public String getClaimProcess(Model  model,Locale locale)
{

    EntityTypes[] entityTypeArray = entityTypes.values();
    model.addAttribute("entityTypes", entityTypeArray);
    return "ClaimProcess";
}

<select style="width:60%;" class="form-control" id="sel1">
                <option th:each="entity , index : ${entityTypes}"
                        th:value="${index.index}"
                        th:text="#{i1}"></option> 
</select>
```

So i want to increment i1 to i2,i3,i4 so on.... please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a message with a dynamic key, you can use the [`#messages`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1) object, doing something like this:

```
<option th:each="entity , index : ${entityTypes}"
    th:value="${index.index}"
    th:text="${#messages.msg('i' + index.index)}"></option>
```

That is, construct the string of the message key you want to use, and pass it to the `#messages.msg` method.